Magento 2 - how to display discount price
I created a table in the price box to display the quantity and discount percentage. I would like to also show the discounted price in this table.
For example, if the product price is $100


Similar to Buy 5 for $5.44 and save 16% and
Buy 10 for $4.87 and save 25%?

I believe you were using Tier pricing which offers a quantity discount to members of a specific customer group and website.
To add the table structure to display the quantity, discount percentage, and savings in price.phtml.  For example:
<?php
// Get the current product object
$product = $_product; // $_product is the current product object passed in the context

// Get the product price
$basePrice = $product->getPrice();

// Get the tier prices
$tierPrices = $product->getTierPrices();

if (!empty($tierPrices)) : ?>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>QTY</th>
                <th>Discount</th>
                <th>Save</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <?php foreach ($tierPrices as $tierPrice) :
                $tierQty = $tierPrice->getQty();
                $tierPriceValue = $tierPrice->getPrice();
                $discountPercentage = (($basePrice - $tierPriceValue) / $basePrice) * 100;
                $savings = ($basePrice - $tierPriceValue) * $tierQty;
            ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo (int)$tierQty; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo number_format($discountPercentage, 2); ?>%</td>
                <td><?php echo '$' . number_format($savings, 2); ?></td>
            </tr>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
<?php endif; ?>


I tried this code and it worked perfectly
$Discountpercentage = intval($block->formatPercent($tierPriceModel->getSavePercent($price['price'])));   
$regularPrice = $product->getPriceInfo()->getPrice('regular_price')->getValue();   
$numproduct = $price['price_qty'];   
$totaldiscount = number_format((($regularPrice/100)*$Discountpercentage)*$numproduct,0);
echo $totaldiscount;

